# Delayed job stopped working after changing server from passenger to puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

Recently I just changed server for my production environment from passenger to puma. Before puma delayed job was working fine without any error but after puma it stopped working.

I am running 3 Delayed job to handle incoming requests on two different servers by dividing them as server 1 : 1 Job and server 2 : 2 Jobs.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -i first --queues=job_1,job_2 start
```

This command I am using to start delayed job after deployment. I am using Capistrano 3 for deployment. Also I have upgrade version of Capistrano version 2 to 3.

In Capistrano 2 we had

```
require 'delayed/recepies'
```

but as per delayed job official documentation I have created a rake task and executing in order to start job again.

It creates a new entry in delayed_jobs table as Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.

What's wrong I am doing here? Is there any worker not listening to my incoming calls? Should I need to start additional things?

----UPDATED----

This is the rake task I have created to restart the jobs.

```
task :restart do
  on roles(delayed_job_roles) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        execute('cd #{current_path};RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -i first --queues=job_1,job_2 stop')
        execute('cd #{current_path};RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -i second --queues=job_1,job_2 start')
      end
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:publishing', 'delayed_job:restart'
```

As I have mentioned that I am running two seperate servers to manage delayed_jobs. On server 2 delayed_job.log file is not updated with latest logs. When I try to run delayed_job it executes on server 1 instead of server 2. Queues are running over server 2 to handle those jobs and when it runs on server 1 it couldn't find the exact source, which I am looking for to get executed.

Comment: Seems unlikely that switching from passenger to puma has an effect on delayed_job. It is more likely that updating and changing capistrano recipes caused the issue. Can you please show the rake task you created and explain how you run it? Furthermore, did you check the servers if there are actually delayed_job workers running? Are there any relevant entries in your log files (deploy log, production/delayed-job log, server error log?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for reply! I just updated question please take a look.

Comment: @spickermann For logs : Yes I can see updated logs for production & deploy. I am also running Monit to handle delayed_jobs to start & stop. Even Monit it self fails to execute.

Comment: @spickermann Did you see updates in question? I am using Apache + Puma.